# got out of my git local branch somehow

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I'm using git and sourceTree software.

I have committed some changes

**all i want to do is to have all change in local cancun_elad and push to remote cancun_elad.**

but when I try to push it I get an error:

[image]

sourceTree:

[image]

Comment: What do you get for `git branch`?

Comment: $ git branch
........* (detached from 0c32451)
........  cancun_elad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a new branch

`git checkout -b mybranch`

Then switch to one of the existing branches

`git checkout cancun_elad`

Then merge in the changes from your old branch

`git merge mybranch`

Then push your changes to the remote

`git push origin cancun_elad`

Comment: all i want to do is to have al change in local cancun_elad and push to remote cancun_elad. Does this fits your answer?